# I need a duration picker in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need a duration picker in javascript
Like in Days: Hours: Minutes: seconds.

Four text boxes for Days,Hours,Minutes,seconds

Comment: That isn't a question.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Please post what you have tried.

Comment: I check http://jsfiddle.net/xHzMw/1/

Comment: But its not working when i change values from keyboard

Comment: check dis https://jqueryui.com/spinner/#time

Comment: I need  Days,Hours,Minutes,seconds all in one spinner

Comment: can you provide a picture or a link to an example of what your looking for? Duration of what? Counting down/up? You need to clarify what you are asking and what you have tried so far

Comment: use a time picker and convert the time to seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `days` field, just copy the format of other fields and update the value from 60 to 24.

But as you mentioned about change values from keyboard, you should choose [form events](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/form-events/) or [keyboard events](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/keyboard-events/) to do that. In this demo, I chose the [blur](https://api.jquery.com/blur/) event because it will trigger when the input loses focus.

```
$("input[name='value']").blur(function() {
     var id = $(this).prop('id');
     $("#" + id).spinner('stepUp');
     $("#" + id).spinner('stepDown');
 });
```

After you add the keyboard event, you should consider about the user input a number more than 60 seconds. There is one example, In your original code, if user input `130` into the `second` field it will update to `1 minute and 70 seconds` but not `2 minutes and 10 seconds`.

You can use `mod` to fix that.

```
$('#seconds').spinner({
     spin: function (event, ui) {
         if (ui.value >= 60) {
             $('#minutes').spinner('stepUp', ui.value / 60);
             $(this).spinner('value', ui.value % 60);
             return false;
         } else if (ui.value < 0) {
             if($('#minutes').spinner('value') > 0) {
                 $(this).spinner('value', ui.value + 60);
                 $('#minutes').spinner('stepDown');
             }
             return false;
         }
     }
 });
```

Here is the [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ssk7833/81yrcdzj/).